# Change preference background color

Tags: java, android, background-color

I have created custom preference by extending Preference class.
And I would like to set its background color to my own. How can I achieve this?
I have tried to set it in `onBindView(View v)`, but I cant figure it out.

Comment: Do you want to change background for a single preference item or for whole screen with preferences?

Comment: Single. It would be best without creating custom layout.